# Changed root password for MySQL now zurmo wont connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

If anyone is familiar with zurmo CRM.. I recently changed my Root password for MySQL and Zurmo now gives me this error... makes sense that zurmo can no longer connect to its  database.. but I need to know which config file to update the new password..

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Ubuntu fixed this issue for me